# Display contents of static files across multiple pages in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, static, blogs

I'm making an incredibly simple PHP blog which takes txt files from a directory and displays them, one after another, on a PHP page. This is fine, but I'm planning to have 365 of these files so it'd be nice to show them on multiple pages, Wordpress-style. What would the PHP be to generate these pages on the fly, say, to display 20 files per page?

The PHP I have to display the files is as follows:

```
function printFile($file) {
  $handle = fopen("$file", "r");
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    echo fgets($handle) . "<br>";
  }
  echo "<hr>";
  fclose($handle);
}



$files = scandir($directory); 
$number = count($files, 0);
while ($number > 2) {
  $number--; 
  $FileToPrint = $directory . $files["$number"];
  echo $FileToPrint . "<br>";
  printFile("$FileToPrint");
}
```

Comment: You can replace your `printFile($file)` function with a simple call to [`readfile($file)`](http://www.php.net/readfile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
// initialize some settings
$perPage = 20;
$page = intval($_GET['page']);

// getting the files (just *.txt)
$files = glob('directory/*.txt');
$numFiles = count($files);

// displaying the files for this page
$offset = $page * $perPage;
for($i = $offset; $i < ($offset + $perPage); $i++){
    // just print the filename for now
     echo $files[$i]. "<br>";
}


// page browser
$numPages = ceil($numFiles / $perPage);
for($i = 0; $i < $numPages; $i++){
    echo '<a href="yourpage.php?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: You've got a potential undefined index error there. The loop would be better as `for ($i = $offset, $count = min($offset + $perPage, $numFiles); $i < $count; $i++)`

Comment: Also, offset calculation should be `($page - 1) * $perPage`.

Comment: What would the code be to display the files in reverse order? I'm only just learning about for loops and so far haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: run a `rsort($files)` after the `glob()` to sort them in reverse order